# Delete all N elements from list

Tags: prolog

I want to write a program which deletes every Nth element from a list without the last one. My program is already working fine and gives me the correct result, but when I ask for another result, prolog comes with the error ">/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated". Here is the code I have so far:

```
delete_elements([],0,[]).
delete_elements([],_,[_|_]).
delete_elements(L,N,R) :-
    length(L,LL),
    LL > N,
    nth1(N,L,_,RZ),
    NZ is N + 1,
    delete_elements(RZ,NZ,RR),
    R = RR.
delete_elements(L,N,R) :-
    length(L,LL),
    LL =< N,
    delete_elements([],_,R),
    L = R.
```

I think that there is something wrong with the cancellation condition of the recursion. How to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the clause:

```
delete_elements(L,N,R) :-
    length(L,LL),
    LL =< N,
    delete_elements([],_,R),
    L = R.
```

You have finished your work but you still call your predicate with an anonymous variable instead of N. You could just write:

```
delete_elements(L,N,L) :-
    length(L,LL),
    LL =< N.
```

Example:

```
?- delete_elements([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3],3,L).
L = [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3] ;
false.
```

For what you asked in your comment my implementation would be:

```
 delete_elements(L,N,R) :- delete_elements(L,1,N,R).

delete_elements([],_,_,[]).
delete_elements([X],N,N,[X]).
delete_elements([X|Xs],N,N,Rs):- length([X|Xs],Y),Y>1,delete_elements(Xs,1,N,Rs).
delete_elements([X|Xs],P,N,[X|Rs]):- P < N,P1 is  P+1,delete_elements(Xs,P1,N,Rs).
```

Comment: Thanks! You know why the program only works for N = 2? How to make the program work for every N(1,3 and so on)?

Comment: For example when I ask for delete_elements([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],3,R) the output should be R=[1,2,4,5,7,8,9], because the last element (9) should be in the list.

Comment: Edited the answer, your answer had many mistakes and I don't think it could work... I gave my implementation instead...

Comment: Sorry for posting my question again, I just tried to made your code a bit easier for me to understand and now it doesn't seem to work. I need an implementation without operators like "->" and ";". :/

Comment: Posted at other question

Comment: Edited the answer without ';' and '->' and now works fine . Pleas remove the other post it is not right to ask duplicate questions...

Comment: Thanks, I will remove my other post. The only thing is when I now ask for "delete_elements([1,2,3,4,5],2,R)." it gives me the result "R = [1, 3, 5]" twice...

Comment: Yes because two clauses fit the same input (this is not wrong answer) , I will edit my answer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129105/discussion-between-zer0kai-and-coder).